# SAS: How to perform regression on array data?

Tags: sas

In SAS, I have an array `x` and a variable `y`. How can I run a linear regression of `y` as a function of the array elements in `x`?

For example, here is a code sample that produces an array:

```
data X;
do i=1 to 10 by 0.1;
    y = exp(i/2);
    array x{5};
    do k=1 to 5;
        x[k] = k*i;
    end;
    output;
end;
run;
```

And here is my failed attempt to do the regression:

```
proc reg data=X outest=regest;
    model y = x;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: Your code creates a dataset with y, x1, x2,...,x5. So you dont have a "x" variable in your dataset X, but reg needs an existing variable. You can do model y= x1 x2 x3 x4 x5; but you will get no results for x2-x5 because they are a linear combination of x1 and also i am not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: @kl78 I created the array just as an example for the question, so we don't need to care if the x's are linearly dependent.  I'm interested in How I could perform the regression without writing the long model y=x1 x2 x3 x4 x5.

Comment: I am still not 100% sure if i understand what you want, but you could write model y=x:; which would include all variables starting with x.

Comment: @kl78 that is the answer to my question! If it would be written as an answer (and not a comment) I would mark it as the answer to my question...

Comment: This is called a variable list, see the different ways here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/68089/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0wphcpsfgx6o7n1sjtqzizp1n39.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array variables are numbered, so array x{5}; creates variables x1,x2,x3,x4,x5.  Proc reg needs all variables listed. With a : you can tell sas to list all variables which start with the given letters, so the solution would be:

```
model y=x:;
```

which in your case would resolve to

```
model y = x1 x2 x3 x4 x5;
```

but would also work with another number of x-Variables.
You only need to be sure, to have no other variables which start with x in your dataset.